# Is there any way to exclude extra AWS Maven dependencies in pom.xml?

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, maven

I have used AWS SQS service in my application for that I have added SQS dependency in maven pom.xml. But once I build application using maven it downloads lots of unused AWS jars and package it with application war file. Is there any way where I can include only required AWS dependencies in application. Maven exclude not possible because have to find the dependency and the have to exclude it in pom.xml

Here is dependencies I have added in pom.xml

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
        <artifactId>aws-java-sdk</artifactId>
        <version>1.11.316</version>
    </dependency>

   <dependency>
        <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
        <artifactId>aws-java-sdk-ses</artifactId>
        <version>1.11.316</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
        <artifactId>aws-java-sdk-sqs</artifactId>
        <version>1.11.316</version>
    </dependency>
```

Refer attached screenshot:

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Instead of declaring a dependency on the entire AWS Java SDK, you should be able to [just include the sqs dependency](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.amazonaws/aws-java-sdk-sqs/1.11.756), like this:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
    <artifactId>aws-java-sdk-sqs</artifactId>
    <version>1.11.756</version>
</dependency>
```

I believe that will also pull in the `aws-java-sdk-core` dependency, but that is all.

Comment: Yes, I have included sqs-sdk only but its also loads lots of unused jars

Comment: @PankajPatel You need to show your pom file in your question then, instead of a screenshot of your jar files.

Comment: I have updated question description and added pom.xml entry foe aws dependency

Comment: Remove the `<artifactId>aws-java-sdk</artifactId>` dependency.